# GEE: arraySlice to find first, second, third, etc. entries in image array

Tags: google-earth-engine, array, change-detection

I'm working off of a great tutorial on continuous change detection from [this book chapter.](https://google-earth-engine.com/Interpreting-Image-Series/Fitting-Functions-to-Time-Series/) I use the tutorial data and code to demonstrate the issue I'm encountering.

Using a stored array image, we can find the date of the first disturbance during the reference period:

```
var resultsPath =
    'projects/gee-book/assets/F4-7/Rondonia_example_small';
var ccdResults = ee.Image(resultsPath);
Map.centerObject(ccdResults, 10);
print(ccdResults);

// Select time of break and change probability array images.
var change = ccdResults.select('tBreak');
var changeProb = ccdResults.select('changeProb');

// Set the time range we want to use and get as mask of places that meet the condition.
var start = 2000;
var end = 2021;
var mask = change.gt(start).and(change.lte(end)).and(changeProb.eq(
1));

Map.addLayer(changeProb, {}, 'change prob');

// Obtain the first change in that time period.
var dates = change.arrayMask(mask).arrayPad([1]);
var firstChange = dates
    .arraySlice(0, 0, 1)
    .arrayFlatten([
        ['firstChange']
    ])
    .selfMask();
   
Map.addLayer(firstChange, 'First change');
```

The tutorial doesn't provide instructions for determining the second change. But given documentation of arraySlice, I figured that doing this would require arraySlice(0, 1, 2), going from the first object in the array to the second. But when I run:

```
var secondChange = dates
    .arraySlice(0, 1, 2)
    .arrayFlatten([
        ['secondChange']
    ])
    .selfMask();
    
Map.addLayer(secondChange, 'Second change');
```

The console returns to error:

```
Second change: Tile error: Input array has length 0 on axis 0, but 1 labels provided.
```

How do I obtain the second object in each grid-cell's array in the dates image array?

Full code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a5358b9a71b83a52fe153ff7931fe2fb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've encountering is that some pixels have no second object, so the `flatten` fails.  You could mask off everything where the arrayLength is less than 2, then it should work.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you!!